# How to send a jpeg data on server-client?

Tags: c++, opencv, client-server

I am using a client - server communication to transfer an image , when i capture an image from my camera its an rgb array which i encode to jpeg format by using imencode.

```
vector<unsigned char>buff;
imencode(".jpg",img,buff);
```

How to send it to the client side and save that data to a .jpg file ?

A simple server side -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<errno.h>

int main(int argc , char **argv)
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , read_size , c , buffer = 0  , n = 0; 
    struct sockaddr_in server , client ; 
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0) ; 
    server.sin_family = AF_INET ; 
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ; 
    server.sin_port = htons(8000) ; 
    if(bind(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server))<0)
    { 
        puts("bind failed") ; 
        return 1; 
    }
    puts("Binding was done now waiting for an incoming client") ; 
    listen(socket_desc , 3) ; 
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); 
    if((new_socket = accept(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&client ,  
(socklen_t*)&c)))
    {
        puts("accepted your connection request") ; 
    }
    fflush(stdout) ; 

    if(new_socket<0)
    {
        puts("Looks like connection with cliento was not a success"); 
    }
    image = cv::imread("a.jpg") ; 
    std::vector<uchar> buff ; 
    cv::imencode(".jpg" , image , buff) ; 

    // Sending a normal mssg instead of jpeg data 
    char send[] = {'a' , 'b' , 'c'} ; 
    n = write(new_socket , send , 10) ; 

    if(n<0)
    {
        puts("Looks like there was an error while writing to client") ; 
    }

    close(socket_desc); 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

The client side -

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<unistd.h>  
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<errno.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    // variable initialization 
    int socket_desc , n = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *parray;
    char buffer[256];
    // creating a socket 
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Socket couldn't be created");
    }

    // do servo initialization 
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.137.3");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8000 );

    // Finally connect to servo 
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0) 
    {
        cout<<strerror(errno);
        close(socket_desc);
        puts("There was a connection error with server");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Successfully got connected with server") ; 
    n = read(socket_desc,buffer,255);

    if (n < 0) {
        perror("There was an error reading from server");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Here is the message from server: %s\n",buffer);
    close(socket_desc) ; 
    return 0 ; 
 }
```

When client sends a request all I need to do is capture an image which will be in RGB format and then encode it to jpeg format, send it to client and then on the client side read it and save it to a .jpg file.

Comment: There are certainly some potential issues with your code. But basically, it looks like you've got it: 1) You've got a socket client connecting to a socket server, 2) Each connect, the server sends a binary stream (i.e. sends the bytes in the .jpg file),   TBD: 3) Each connect, the client  *reads* the entire binary stream (it's not doing that yet, and it should probably do it in a loop), 4) then the client writes the entire stream (to a file), and 5) closes the file, and closes the socket.  That's it!  Look here for more details on "sockets programming": https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: imho, you should do it the other way round - the *client* should take a picture, connect to the server, and send the image there.

Comment: I see you already have a program. Are you asking how to write the program you've already written? Is there something wrong with that program?

Comment: On the server side i have my jpeg data in std::vector buff , how to write it to client and read on the client side to write it to a jpg file ...the write function on my server takes only character buffer as input

Comment: Use `curl` library for client-server case

Comment: your mixing C and C++ code in undesirable ways.  Just as a simple example, `#include <stdio.h>` is only for C code, for C++ use `#include <cstdio>`  Suggest separating the two languages and then, given the use of the `vector` from the C++ STL suggest only use the C++ language.

Comment: Since the posted code is C++, please remove the 'c' tag and add the 'c++' tag